# Optimizing Performance on Table with Bulk Inserts and Queries

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

We have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Measurement (
  HubId bigint NOT NULL
  ,DeviceId bigint NOT NULL
  ,Timestamp datetime NOT NULL
  ,Value bigint NOT NULL
)
```

We'd like to import records into this table at approximately 100,000 records a second which will be split across multiple concurrent connections. I can achieve this level of performance by treating the table as a heap (i.e. no indexes) and using `SqlBulkCopy`. Every second there are 100,000 unique `HubId` and `DeviceId` combinations with the `Timestamp` incrementing. `Value` is cumulative over time.

We also have the requirement to read the two most recent (last and second to last in this case - insert is always in order) values `GROUP BY HubId, DeviceId` once per second but only for a subset of the rows (ones that the user is interested in) to produce a realtime difference between the last two values.

In addition we need to aggregate the data once every 15 minutes into 15 minute slices for historical purposes. This data is aggregated based upon the maximum value from the previous 15 minute slice and the maximum from the current 15 minute slice... This needs to occur across the entire dataset but can be split across multiple connections for unique `HubId` and `DeviceId` combinations. Because `Value` is cumulative this is effectively the last value for the previous and current 15 minute slice.

Bulk inserting into the table with indexes results in escalation to an exclusive table lock. In addition we can't seem to get the queries to perform without escalating to exclusive table locks.

Can anybody give me some pointers as to the best way of structuring this? I'm banging my head against the wall trying to work out the best way to go...

Thanks,
Dean

Comment: Might be worth it to try [table partitioning](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/partitioning.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much to-ing and fro-ing we've changed our approach somewhat in order to achieve the throughput we require. As it turns out we only care about the 100,000 records/sec at the instant they are there and they are used to update a continually rolling set of aggregated and realtime values.

We bulk insert the 100,000 rows using a number of worker threads into temporary heap tables (so using 4 worker threads, each is handling around 25,000 rows) and then apply a clustered index to the temporary table. We then MERGE the data from the temporary table directly into the realtime and aggregate tables and drop the temporary table. Here we use the ROWLOCK hint to force SQL to take a ROWLOCK rather than a TABLOCK or PAGLOCK which would cause greater contention than necessary across the worker threads.

In addition we changed our in-memory data structure to be a lossy stack rather than a queue. In our case this is suitable because we generally only care about the most recent data and it's OK to drop older data.

We'll be using partitioning as the ace in our pocket, but we're currently limited to SQL Server Standard Edition so we can't deploy it outside of our development machines just now.

Cheers,
Dean